# "Please hold the handrail during the whole journey" in Chinese/Cantonese? (As heard in Hong Kong airport trains)

Tags: translation, meaning, cantonese, hong-kong

I have rode this *automated people mover* inside Hong Kong airport and the voice always says **"Please hold the handrail during the whole journey"** everytime when the train starts to move and after announcing the next stop. How do you write it in Chinese (or maybe even in Cantonese)?

> If you don't know what I mean, here is the link to it:
>   https://youtu.be/-CgqmrWGIEY?t=54
>
> (P.S. That is not my YouTube video, just an example)

*Thank you very much in advance to those who answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video the Mandarin is:

> 請沿途緊握扶手

---

This [Google webcache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ni3ntJ7CI2gJ:https://issuu.com/metro_china/docs/20120831_cn_hong-kong%20&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=tw) also says:

> 九巴的勸喻，貼在車廂扶手左右：「 上 車 後 請 沿 途 緊 握 扶 手 」，英 語「 Please hold the handrail during the whole journey. 」為 九 巴 的 愛 心 ，我 不 能 不 長 嘆，釋放善意。

It seems like a common saying on public transportation in HK.

Answer (score 0):

Try 请(您)全程握紧扶手. Compare to 请您全程系好安全带.